# I'm missing something in the Servicestack session documentation

Tags: c#, session, servicestack

In the ServiceStack session documentation here:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions

there is some example code that defines a UserSession property. I expected that the setter for the property would add the newly-created data storage object to the cache. Is that missing from this sample code? Or is there some other place the session data is added to the cache?

Also, why do we have both a sessionId and a sessionKey? Wouldn't the latter be sufficient? And we create multiple Ids (CreateSessionIds) but only ever use one (GetSessionId)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SessionId is just the hashed Guid, SessionKey is the [unique fully-qualified key](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/SessionFeature.cs#L64) that's used when referencing the session in the datastore (e.g. Redis).

There exists both transient and permanent session keys defined and the one used is specified by the `ss-opt` cookie and can be changed by the client at anytime.

Comment: This answers the secondary questions, but not the primary question about the missing Add call.

Comment: A new empty session and has no effect that it's stored or not so we decided not to. It gets set everytime you assign a dynamic session field. For typed Sessions you need to explicitly call [IServiceBase|IHttpRequest].SaveSession() ext method when you want to save it. Note: The built-in AuthProviders automatically saves the session when it needs to.